# Typeset cftchapfont as uppercase

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, capitalization

I'm trying to put the whole `cftchapfont` as uppercase using `tocloft` package.

```
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\MakeUppercase}
```

does not work at all (it actually messes up everything), nor does:

```
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\MakeUppercase\chaptertitlename\;}
```

which only capitalizes `\chaptertitlename`, nor does:

```
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\MakeUppercase\chaptertitlename\;\MakeUppercase}
```

which only capitalizes the first letter of SNUM (and I've got words such as "premier" for the first chapter).

How can I make sure the whole thing is uppercase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to patch the `\@chapter` command, which is responsible for writing the entries in the auxiliary files. The lines

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}
```

and

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
```

should read with `\MakeUppercase{#1}` instead of `#1`.

Answer (score 1):

I actually ideally wanted small caps, but the font didn't have any. What I did was:

- edit the TTF in fontforge;
- add small caps from fontforge;
- save new font as OTF;
- load font with `Letters=SmallCap` in fontspec.

and it did what I wanted.