# Error when trying to use \MakeTextUppercase to customize the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, errors, memoir, capitalization

I get the following error when trying to use `\MakeTextUppercase` to customize the table of contents:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\find@pdflink ...ode \protected@edef \Hy@testname 
                                              {#2}\ifx \Hy@testname \@em... 
l.2 ...entsline {chapter}{Contents}{1}{section*.1}
```

Any idea of what's going on? I've included a minimum example below for testing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, english]{memoir}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\MakeTextUppercase}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: This compiles fine for me with TeXLive 2010

Comment: Try compiling it twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [typeset cftchapfont as uppercase](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23558/typeset-cftchapfont-as-uppercase)

Comment: Although related, this is a separate question, since the error here is generated by `hyperref`, and the problem is related to how `memoir` and `hyperref` interact.  See [this thread](http://goo.gl/cWbnI) on comp.text.tex for related discussion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I remember `\MakeUppercase` and `\MakeTextUppercase` can easily break, also with hyperref.

Before you try to fix that, I suggest considering using small caps shape instead. That's much better than all caps, from a typographic view. This declaration works:

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\scshape}
```

[image: table of contents with small caps]

If it's really required, it can be solved by redefining memoir's `\l@chapter`, which is responsible for printing the chapter TOC entry, using `\uppercase` (`\MakeTextUppercase` and `\Makeuppercase` would break here as well):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \l@chapapp{\uppercase{#1}}{#2}{\cftchaptername}}
\makeatother
```

[image: all caps in TOC chapter entry]

(This time with hyperref link border, which can be removed by options.)

Comment: While this is good stylistic advice, what if the formatting specifications *require* uppercase?

Comment: @Alan: in that case I would redefine `\l@chapter` I'll show it

Comment: Actually, at the moment it _is_ formatted as small caps. And as there apparently is no elegant fix I think I'll stick to it. And as you said, it is good style to use small caps rather than upper case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I ended up with on [this question from April](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11892/hyperref-breaks-my-all-caps-toc-entries) (might want close this as a duplicate, or not). In my particular case, I needed to only make the chapter titles uppercase, and leave the appendix titles alone. I didn't want to keep a full copy of the `\@chapter` or related commands around, but there's the potential for long-term breakage either way if your code lives for many years (either the patch I use will fail, or your old copy of the `\@chapter` or related commands won't work the same way as the newer versions expect):

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\ifpatchable*{\@chapter}{\typeout{Chapter can be patched}}{\typeout{Chapter cannot be patched}}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}%
{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}}%
{\let\f@rtocold\f@rtoc \def\f@rtoc{\uppercase\expandafter{\f@rtocold}} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}}%
{\typeout{Succeeded}}%
{\typeout{Failed}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\appendix \appendixpage
\chapter{Alpha}
\end{document}
```

Since I still have some number of users with PC-TeX who don't get e-TeX support by default, I also have this option using the `ted` package.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{ted}
\makeatletter
\Substitute*[{\gdef\@chapter[##1]##2}]{\@chapter[#1]{#2}}%
{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}}%
{\let\f@rtocold\f@rtoc%
 \def\f@rtoc{\texorpdfstring{\uppercase\expandafter{\f@rtocold}}{\f@rtocold}}%
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\appendix \appendixpage
\chapter{Alpha}
\end{document}
```

[image]