# How to apply Memoir manual's fix to allow \MakeTextUppercase in toc with hyperref

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, memoir

There is a known conflict between the `memoir` class and the `hyperref` package. `hyperref` cannot process Table of Contents headings that include the `\MakeTextUppercase` macro.

The `memoir` manual (`texdoc memoir`) provides a bit of code that is supposed to fix the problem, but I can't get it to work.

**Am I using the manual's solution incorrectly, or is another solution required?**

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand*{\cftpartfont}{\MakeTextUppercase}

% From Memoir manual p. 158
\makeatletter
\settocpreprocessor{part}{%
    \let\tempf@rtoc\f@rtoc%
    \def\f@rtoc{%
        \texorpdfstring{\MakeTextUppercase{\tempf@rtoc}}{\tempf@rtoc}}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\part{A Whale}
\chapter{A Tale}
\section{A Sail}
\subsection{A Beachball}

\part{A Poodle}
\chapter{A Noodle}
\section{A Doodle}

\end{document}
```

Compiling this MWE I get the following error:

```
! Argument of \contentsline has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.2 \contentsline
                  {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}A Tale}{5}
```

Other solutions have been proposed:

- [Typeset cftchapfont as uppercase](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23558/typeset-cftchapfont-as-uppercase?lq=1)
- [Error when trying to use \MakeTextUppercase to customize the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25694/error-when-trying-to-use-maketextuppercase-to-customize-the-table-of-contents)

But ideally the solution in the class manual would be the correct one.

Comment: Simply comment `\renewcommand*{\cftpartfont}{\MakeTextUppercase}` and it compiles fine.

Comment: @karlkoeller Yes, that line is what makes this a non-working example. The idea is to use memoir's interface to automatically uppercase certain headings in the toc. But when you process such a document with hyperref, it breaks. The question is how to fix that so the line you mentioned can be preserved.

Comment: So you're looking for a workaround different from the one suggested by `memoir`'s manual, aren't you?

Comment: @karlkoeller I would like to know why the one suggested in the manual, which I use literally above, does not work.

Comment: It does. The manual says that changing `\cftpartfont` doesn't work...

Comment: @karlkoeller I misunderstood the manual. I am supposed to use the `\settocpreprocessor` command *instead of* the `\cftpartfont` command. If you write that as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding `memoir`'s manual.

It says that when loading `hyperref` you can't set an uppercase font for parts in the ToC with

```
\renewcommand*{\cftpartfont}{\MakeTextUppercase}
```

It says that you can instead use `\settocpreprocessor` in this way:

```
\makeatletter
\settocpreprocessor{part}{%
    \let\tempf@rtoc\f@rtoc%
    \def\f@rtoc{%
        \texorpdfstring{\MakeTextUppercase{\tempf@rtoc}}{\tempf@rtoc}}%
}
\makeatother
```

So simply removing the offending line from your MWE gives the desired result

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%\renewcommand*{\cftpartfont}{\MakeTextUppercase}

% From Memoir manual p. 158
\makeatletter
\settocpreprocessor{part}{%
    \let\tempf@rtoc\f@rtoc%
    \def\f@rtoc{%
        \texorpdfstring{\MakeTextUppercase{\tempf@rtoc}}{\tempf@rtoc}}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\part{A Whale}
\chapter{A Tale}
\section{A Sail}
\subsection{A Beachball}

\part{A Poodle}
\chapter{A Noodle}
\section{A Doodle}

\end{document}
```

[image]