# hyperref link expanded by MakeUpperCase breaks

Tags: hyperref, koma-script, classicthesis

Short version:

How can I solve the problem of using hyperref links when expanded by MakeUpperCase?

Long version:
If I try to redefine:

```
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace*{\labelsep}%
\small\spacedallcaps{#1}}
```

where:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\sffamily%
\textssc{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}%
```

So when I want to use a description:

```
\begin{description}
\item[{\hyperref[cap:first]{first chapter}}] Bla bla
\end{description}
```

The link doesn't work because hyperref is looking for `CAP:FIRST`.

How can I fix it (yeah, I could redefine all the lowercase label to uppercase, but I guess there could be something else that works.

Edit:

I am not always using `hyperref` within the `description`, but I would prefer to keep the MakeUpperCase, rather than rewriting every description item. 
I mean, if I really have to do it, I can, (as I could redefine the labels), but I am still interested in a more general solution (if it exists).

Comment: What is your documentclass? There is a known conflict between `hyperref` and `memoir` with `\MakeTextUpperCase`.

Comment: Komascript+classicthesis

Comment: It might be the same underlying problem. It's discussed in the `memoir` manual and in this question by me: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219134/how-to-apply-memoir-manuals-fix-to-allow-maketextuppercase-in-toc-with-hyperre

Comment: Tell us a little more about your usage of the `description` environment. Do you *always* have a `\hyperref` in there? Also, why not just use `\hyperref[..]{FIRST CHAPTER}`? How extensive is this usage? Don't try to build a castle when all you need is a doll house.

Comment: I am not always using `hyperref` within the `description`, but I would prefer to keep the MakeUpperCase, rather than rewriting every description item. 
I mean, if I really have to do it, I can, (as I could redefine the labels), but I am still interested in a more general solution (if it exists).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir), the following works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newif\ifhyperrefindesclabel

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \let\oldhyperref\hyperref% Store \hyperref in \oldhyperref
  \hyperrefindesclabelfalse% No \hyperref in description
  \renewcommand{\hyperref}[2][]{% Update \hyperref to
    \gdef\h@optarg{##1}% ... store optional argument
    \gdef\h@manarg{##2}% ... store mandatory argument
    \global\hyperrefindesclabeltrue}% ... and mark as \hyperref-being-used
  \setbox1=\hbox{#1}% Evaluate \descriptionlabel argument
  \hspace*{\labelsep}% Insert space
  \small% Change font
  \ifhyperrefindesclabel% Was \hyperref used?
    \oldhyperref[\h@optarg]{\spacedallcaps\h@manarg}% Call \oldhyperref
  \else% ... no \hyperref was used
    \spacedallcaps{#1}% Re-set label using \spacedallcaps
  \fi
  }
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\sffamily%
  \textsc{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}%

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{First section}\label{sec:first}

\begin{description}
  \item[{\hyperref[sec:first]{first section}}] Bla bla

  \item[second section] Bla bla
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

The idea behind the enlarged `\descriptionlabel` definition is to set a flag (`\ifhyperrefindesclabel`) whenever you use `\hyperref` inside a `description` label. Depending on this condition, `\hyperref` is restored in a modified way to use `\spacedallcaps` in the second/mandatory argument *only*.

Comment: it works also in koma-script.