# Classicthesis/glossaries: glossary entry in paragraph

Tags: glossaries, classicthesis

My question is related to: [hyperref link expanded by MakeUpperCase breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225451/hyperref-link-expanded-by-makeuppercase-breaks)

I use the same document setup as in the question (classicthesis+koma).

I would like to make a reference to a glossary entry in a \paragraph statement, e.g:
`\paragraph{My reference \glsxtrshort{OUP}}`

The thing is that is does not compile because classisthesis defines `\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\textls[80]{\ct@caps\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
}{\relax}`
and the makeTextLowercase breaks the label. I also tried \glsxtrshort{\MakeTextUpperCase{OUP}} but this also does not help.

I could not transfer the answer in the link to the glossaries package.

A workaround would be to define all labels in small letters, but I have thousands of them in the document and there has to be some way around it.
I also don't mind using a custom definition of glsxtrshort just for the paragraphs.

Comment: I'd try \NoCaseChange from the textcase package https://ctan.org/pkg/textcase. That is, \NoCaseChange{\glsxtrshort{OUP}}

Comment: Hi Philipp. Thanks a lot! Your suggestion partly works. The acronym is being created correctly, however this results in a font change. I tried defining `\newcommand{\acrshortpgraph}[1]{\glslink{\NoCaseChange{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\glsentryshort{#1}}}}` but this does not work (complains that the label oup (lower case) is not defined.

Comment: You won't lose much by redefining `\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin] {\normalfont\normalsize}{\theparagraph}{0pt}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}` so that it doesn't use spacedlowsc. Make it use `\scshape`.

Comment: When you say there's a font change - it can't be another font, you probably get what you'd get from `\textsc{abc ABC} `

Comment: Hey Philip. I should have been more specific. When using \NoCaseChange{\glsxtrshort{OUP}} the link is created, but the acronym has the same font as the regular text and not the spacedlowsmallcaps-font that is used for the paragraph heading. I would rather not like to redefine the original paragraph-heading style. Or did I get that comment wrong?